# Error : Cannot open be opened because its project type(.jsproj) is not supported by this version of the application - VS Express RC 2012 for Windows 8

Tags: javascript, windows-8, projects-and-solutions, visual-studio-2012

Just Started work on `Visual Studio Express RC 2012 for Windows 8`, but when I tried to create my first JavaScript project, it gives an error which says `"ProjectDirectory/ProjectName.jsproj" Cannot open be opened because its project type(.jsproj) is not supported by this version of the application.
To open it please use version that support this type of project.`

Searched a lot for this problem but didn't find this problem using (.jsproj) solution or VS 2012.

For additional information, I have also installed `Visual Studio 11 Beta` on same machine.

I am adding snap shot of error message this will help to get an idea about the problem.

[image: Error : Cannot open be opened because its project type(.jsproj) is not supported by this version of the application - VS Express RC 2012 for Windows 8]

Again please notice its an `JavaScript Project Solution`.

Any idea about this Error?

Comment: As Microsoft error messages go, that one's quite helpful!

Comment: This is the help link http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(vs.projecttypenotavailable)&rd=true

Not seems very help full.

Comment: Yes: both the error message and the Help link show that VS Express 2012 RC for Windows 8 does not handle `.jsproj` files and you need to install a version which does.

Comment: VS Express 2012 for Windows 8 *does* support `.jsproj` project files.  This is an error that can appear when your installation is corrupted (or otherwise certain runtime errors can cause).

Comment: yes that's an error, just figured out the problem and posting as answer @AndrewArnott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue may occur if you're running the beta version of VS 2012 side by side with RC.

Do you have the beta version of VS 2012 installed or was this perhaps an upgrade of a system that had a previous version of Windows 8 installed along with the VS 2012 beta?

Comment: You could also try repairing your VS installation.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for all your contribution, after searching a lot and with you valuable answers, just sorted this problem out.

I had VS 2011 Beta and VS 2012 RC(For Metro App & This one having problem) installed on same machine, it seems they are sharing some resources which is causing this problem.

First I tried to Repair VS 2012 which does't sort out the problem, instead it raise another problem, now VS 2011 Beta start Giving Error "Licence Data ..... uninstall required".

So I removed VS 2011 Beta, now VS 2012 RC working great.

But now another problem it VS 2012 RC is only for Metro APP development.

Q: How if somebody would like continue with .Net Development ?

A: For this now, I am using VS 2010 for this and it works well with it.

That's how it sorted my problem. The End Result is not use VS 2011 Beta with VS 2012
     RC, on Windows 8 Release Preview, instead you can use combination of VS 2010 and VS 
    2012 RC.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "VS 2011 Beta".  I've never heard of it (and I'm on the Visual Studio team :))

Comment: The VS *Express* 2012 RC only allows Metro style app development.  But you can also [download the VS *Ultimate* 2012 RC](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=247148) (for free) that allows full development of all project types.

Comment: @AndrewArnott Don't you heard about **MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 11** it comes out with Windows 8 Consumer Preview, I think.

Comment: @AndrewArnott Thanks for that! i was just not aware of that it comes with .net development too.

Comment: The codename is "Dev11".  The product is "Visual Studio 2012".  There isn't a "Visual Studio 11".

Comment: That's not possible, I have offline setup of it too, and its licence docs tittle is **VS11 Beta EULA**, when i installed it, it always says VS 11. I have Screen Shot of its starting screen of setup, would you like to see?

Comment: By the way its full name is: **Visual Studio 11 Beta Ultimate**, hope you got it now.

Comment: Well, so bit it -- the code name bled into the product name for the beta, which I wasn't aware of.  But it's the same product.